# Interrupt libgdx Action on collision

Tags: java, action, libgdx, collision-detection, game-development

I am developing a game using libgdx. My Gameobjects are all subclasses of Actor. Now i want to take Advantage of the Actions which can be used with the Actors. If my Key-Controlled Player collides with a Computer-Controlled Enemie the Player should be knocked back. I can get this with a moveBy-Action. But when my Player collides with a Wall or another Zombie while he stil moves cause of knockback the Action should interrupt. 
Is there a way to achieve this? Or are Actions not made for things like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of cause there is a way to stop actions.

1. One way would be that you remove the action from your actor with
   `actor.removeAction(Action action)`.
2. You can clear your actors actions with `actor.clearActions()`. This does delete all actions.
3. You can reset your `Action` or `SequenceAction`. `sequence.reset()` or `action.reset()`
4. stop updating the Actions at a collision by overriding the `.act(float delta)` of your actor
5. Else write a `MyAction extends Action` or `MyAction extends
   TemporalAction` type which overrides the `update (float percent)`
   and has a boolean for interrupted. If interrupted don't update if
   not update.

i would recomend take a look into the actions to see how they work and maybe write your own Action that can be interupted. (your own action should be the best because it will be how you like it) Else remove the Action on collision.

Comment: Wow thanks man (: I think i will use the 5th Point (: Sounds great. The 4th Point seems to be useable also for collisions outside of an Action. Thanks

Comment: your welcome. I think the 5th point will be the best so go for it.